# DOM manipulation in Angular directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've read several articles that say manipulating the DOM with jqlite is only acceptable in directives but none of them go on to explain why.

**I understand why it's a bad idea to use jquery/jqlite in controllers, services, etc.** but could someone explain why it is acceptable in directives?

Answer (score 3):

Because they are designed for it.

> Directives are markers on a DOM element that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children.
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

In web-app you need some binding to html. Angular separate logical units (services), model/view-model (controller, his data and methods) and objects which project data/model to html and changes/events to model (directives).